# Nagios BAT file not returning correct status code

Tags: scripting, nagios, batch-file

I've written a batch file for a Windows server to detect whether a particular service is running and if it isn't, return a Critical status back to Nagios. The script works perfectly (as in, it can tell if the process is running or not, I've tried this with a service that's running and a service that isn't), and returns the correct string, but regardless of which string it returns the status within Nagios is always OK.

Here's the code (with various variable names obscured, obviously):

```
@Echo Off
Set ServiceName=ServiceNameGoesHere

SC queryex "%ServiceName%"|Find "STATE"|Find /v "RUNNING">Nul&&(
    echo CRITICAL: Service not running!
    exit /b 2

)||(
    echo OK: Service active.
    exit /b 0
)
```

And here's the matching part in Nagios:

```
define service {
         host_name               myWindowsServer
         use                     local-service
         service_description     Service Active Check
         check_command           check_ncpa!-P 5693 -M 'plugins/service_check.bat'
         notification_options    w,c
         contacts                nagiosadmin
         register                1
}
```

What's odd is that if I run the BAT file manually on the command line of the host server and then run `echo %errorlevel%` it does return the correct status code (2 or 0). Nagios only ever seems to see a 0 status given it keeps returning OK for both, despite getting the correct string.

The vast majority of my servers are Linux so I've only ever written scripts using shell scripting before, and those return statuses correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given that the script returns "OK" for services that do not exist, this is not a Nagios problem. The script is, however, convoluted, which makes it difficult to see the defect.

Comment: The script runs a single command and parses it for a string of RUNNING - if it's there, the script goes down the active route, if it's not, it goes down the other. It's a single if statement, I don't see how that's that convoluted? I fully accept this is more likely to be a Batch issue, the problem is I don't see how when it's returning the status correctly when run from the command line in Windows.

As for the not existing part - I've only run it against service names that do exist, just one that's running and one that is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rejigged the if statement logic and I've got it working:

```
@Echo Off
Set ServiceName=ServiceNameGoesHere

SC queryex "%ServiceName%"|Find "STATE"|Find /v "RUNNING">NUL
if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo CRITICAL: Service not running! & exit /b 2)
if %errorlevel% == 1 (echo OK: Service active. & exit /b 0)
```

This returns 2 when the named service isn't running, and 0 when it is, as well as the correct string.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I have suggested removal of the "nagios" tag from the question though, as this is not strictly Nagios related.